# How do I display the handle for all front-end enqueued scripts in plugin options page?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I use the following function in my plugin to display all the scripts handles in my plugin options page but it display only the handles of admin scripts:

```
function my_detected_scripts() {
  global $wp_scripts;
  foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
    echo $handle . ' <br /> ';
  endforeach;
}
```

Then:

```
echo my_detected_scripts()
```

How can get the handles of all front-end enqueued scripts only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tested and retested your code. Tested it in my theme and plugin, it only prints front end scripts.

Comment: Using the funtion above? That's incredible. By the way, it output the jquery-code too? Thnx.

Comment: Well yes, incredible or not. Your code is not your problem, something else is. Set debug to true in wp_config.php and see if you get any errors. I would suggest to reinstall wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to get the front-end scripts in a script called in the back-end, because the front-end scripts are all registered in scripts called only on the front-end. I think the only way would be to save a transient option including the front-end scripts on front-end page loading and get the transient option via ajax in the back-end. Maybe it will be not the best way, but I don't see other solutions. Then of course you can add all the conditions with nonces ... to save the transient only in specific conditions ...